# how to change the icon color when hovering or clicking on wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a few icons that I would like to change their color by hovering over or clicking on that icon.

I currently use an invisible button over this icon.

My code:

```
<materialDesign:PackIcon
    Kind="Minus"
    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
    Width="16"
    Margin="0,20,85,45"
    Foreground="White"
    Height="16"
/>

<Button Name="Minus"
    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
    Height="Auto"
    Width="18"
    Margin="0,20,85,45"
    BorderThickness="0"
    BorderBrush="#00000000"
    Background="#00000000"
    Click="MininusButton"
/>
```

what I want to do is like this, this example does not show the click part

http://jsfiddle.net/804jeg82/628/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a custom `Button` `Style` and a `Foreground` binding on your icon. Here is an example using a `Rectangle` as a stand-in for the icon.

The custom style changes the `Foreground` brush on `IsMouseOver` and `IsPressed`.

The custom style also has a stripped down control template since you don't need to see the button's visual states.

The icon has a binding to the `Foreground` property of its parent `Button`.

Button Style

```
<Style x:Key="IconButtonStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="18" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="18" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger
            Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsMouseOver}"
            Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger
            Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsPressed}"
            Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Button with Icon (using a Rectangle as a stand-in)

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource IconButtonStyle}">
    <Rectangle
        Width="16"
        Height="16"
        Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}, Path=Foreground}"
        StrokeThickness="0" />
</Button>
```